# 昨日私は十二時過ぎまで 起きた or 起きていた

Tags: meaning

> 昨日私は十二時過ぎまで
>
> 1. 起きた
> 2. 起きていた

I chose 1 in the above statement but it was wrong, 2 - 起きていた is the correct answer
Why is b correct?

My Interpretation:
Yesterday I woke up just past 12 o clock.

Why is the ていた even considered in this kind of statement? I just woke up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

昨日私は十二時過ぎ**に**起きた would have meant "I woke up after 12 o'clock". に marks a time point when something happens.

However, the first half of the actual sentence is 十二時過ぎ**まで**, or "**until** after 12 o'clock". まで in a non-negative sentence refers to the continuation of some action or state.

- 5時まで働く
  to work until 5
- この店は9時まで開いている。
  This shop is open until 9.

In your case, it's the "up/awake status" that has continued until after 12, and the continuation of the result of an instant action is expressed using the -teiru form.

> 昨日私は十二時過ぎまで起きていた。
> I was awake until after 12.
> <sub>(i.e., I woke up (probably in the morning) and that state continued until after 12)</sub>